# What is the size of the kth Superabundant Number?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Utilizing the data generated by T.D. Noe for the first $10^6$ terms of [A004394](https://oeis.org/A004394), a plot of $k$ against $log_{10}(S(k))$ where S(K) is the $k^{th}$ [Superabundant Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superabundant_number) shows a strong linear relationship which suggests the following:

$$S(k)\approx e^{0.242692k}$$

Is this a known result and does this relationship hold past $k=10^6$? Can the exact value of the constant be determined?

[image: Linear Regression of log10(S(k)) against k.]

Comment: Linking to another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294122/what-approach-provides-the-largest-known-verification-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) where I use this result.

Comment: [Briggs](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1175789744) shows a similar result for the density of SAs but not clear how they are related. See Figure 2.