# Can it be proven that the left hand side of Robin's Inequality is bounded by some function?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis

Based on the shape of the curve shown [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3294122/what-approach-provides-the-largest-known-verification-of-the-riemann-hypothesis) and the possible relationship shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297842/what-is-the-size-of-the-kth-superabundant-number), I am willing to venture a conjecture:

$$\frac{\sigma (n)}{e^{\gamma} n \log \log n}<1-\frac{0.242692}{\ln(n)}$$

This conjecture holds for the largest Colossally Abundant Number I could find, the $143215^{th}$ with over 800k digits computed by [Schwabhäuser](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3678.pdf). From his statistics:

$$ \frac{X(n_{143215})}{e^\gamma}=0.99995934<1-\frac{0.242692}{\ln(n_{143215})}=0.999999873$$

Can this bound or something similar be proven to hold for all Superabundant Numbers (and therefore all numbers)?